# What is the proper MVC way to place values when data is not available from the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database

I am developing a sample code and I would like to use 100% MVC technology in a proper way.

I have a view that requests data from the database, if the data exists, then it will be displayed, otherwise it will display some other values:

The view:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>Status: </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="txtStatus" value="@Model.StatusChoice.FirstOrDefault().CurrentStatus" />
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

The Controller:

```
public ActionResult RStatusC(string CurrentStatus)
{
    return View(UpdateMainGrid(CurrentStatus));
}

public DataList UpdateMainGrid(string CurrentStatus)
{
    StatusModel Choices = new StatusModel();
    Choices.GetStatus(DB, CurrentStatus);
    return Choices;
}
```

The Model:

```
public List<RequestedStatusC> GetStatus(DB_Entities DB, string CurrentStatus)
{            
    List<RequestedStatusC> SR = new List<RequestedStatusC>();
    SR = DB.Database.SqlQuery<RequestedStatusC>(@"SELECT CurrentStatus
                                                    FROM MyTable
                                                    WHERE CurrentStatus = {0}
                                                    ORDER BY StatusKey", CurrentStatus).ToList();
    if (!SR.Any()) SR.Add(new RequestedStatusC { CurrentStatus = (CurrentStatus == "" ? "Missing" : CurrentStatus) });
    return SR;
}
```

Is this a proper way? Especially using `if (!SR.Any())` in the **Model**?

Comment: The code works fine, but I want to take full advantage from MVC

Comment: MVC has nothing to do with database access. What you posted as a "model" is actually a data access method that bypasses EF to execute an ADO.NET query directly against the database. If `MyTable` maps to an entity (as it should), why not write `DB.SomeEntities.Where(entity=>entity.CurrentStatus==CurrentStatus).ToList()`?`

Comment: in my opinion there isn't a specific MVC way to achieve this. I usually like to keep any validation checks out of the model and let the controller take this type of decisions. If the model is empty show one view or another. Also don't put too much logic at view level, since it's not unit testable. These are just a few hints, but the rest is up to you how you want the user experience to be on your app.

Comment: This would be an excellent fit on the Code Review exchange.

Comment: If you are wanting to do things the mvc way, then you certainly do not generate inputs that way - you use `HtmlHelper` methods to generate your form controls

Answer (score 0):

you have to try like below code,

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>Status: </td>
            <td>
if(@Model.StatusChoice.FirstOrDefault() != null && @Model.StatusChoice.FirstOrDefault().CurrentStatus != ""){
                <input type="text" name="txtStatus" value="@Model.StatusChoice.FirstOrDefault().CurrentStatus" />
}
else{
<input type="text" name="txtStatus" value="Missing" />
}
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

In your Model remove if condition,

```
public List<RequestedStatusC> GetStatus(DB_Entities DB, string CurrentStatus)
{            
    List<RequestedStatusC> SR = new List<RequestedStatusC>();
    SR = DB.Database.SqlQuery<RequestedStatusC>(@"SELECT CurrentStatus
                                                    FROM MyTable
                                                    WHERE CurrentStatus = {0}
                                                    ORDER BY StatusKey", CurrentStatus).ToList();
    //if (!SR.Any()) SR.Add(new RequestedStatusC { CurrentStatus = (CurrentStatus == "" ? "Missing" : CurrentStatus) });
    return SR;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove if condition in your model, add if condition in your view

```
@if (Model.StatusChoice != null)
{<table>...</table>}
```